# Question closed due to similar questions in the past but the existing answers do not solve my question (the toy model)

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

[Given square matrices A and B, how to solve T obeys Transpose[T]. A . T = B?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293896/given-square-matrices-a-and-b-how-to-solve-t-obeys-transposet-a-t-b)

I don't know who closed my question disregarding my comments multiple times in the bottom citing this

[How to solve for $\mathbf{X}$ in a matrix equation $\mathbf{X A} \mathbf{X}^\top = \mathbf{B}$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251537/95437)

I had mentioned that the requirement of cited questions/answers do not solve my question:

My question and examples require:

1. symmetric integer unimodular matrix A and B,
2. (non-symmetric) integer unimodular matrix T.

My examples and my toy model have such solutions. But the cited answer do not reproduce that answer.

There is a rank-10 toy model. If anyone claims his/her answer works, then please provide the mathematica solution to the rank-10 toy model.

Please don't close the question that deserve a good answer! Thank you!